# When I turn the key to start it it acts like the battery is dead: It wont even click

Tags: gmc, no-crank-no-start, acadia

I have a 2011 GMC Acadia Denali. When I turn the key it doesn't even click, but I still have headlights and interior lights, my gauges work, I can roll my windows down and move my seat (both are electric) nothing dims. I tried to jump start it but it wouldn't even take a jump (didn't change anything when tried to jump start it). I have also replaced the battery thus did not help. I have checked the fuses and relays for the ignition and starter and they are all fine as well. What could be the issue? So far I have been told possibly the starter or maybe the computer and I have also been told that it sounds like it's going into "limp mode" or possibly a ground wire issue. My check engine light is on but these are the only codes I am getting P0455, P0496, U2142, U2100, C0710. My message center also has the following messages on it...traction control is off, service stabilink, service traction control system, also tells me that I have a tire that needs air (but tire is fine) and will randomly tell me tighten gas cap as well. Please help! I can't afford to have an expensive yard ornament! Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: When you try to start the engine, is there power to the starter relay coil?  Does the relay energize?  How did you test the relays?

Answer (score 1):

Your neutral safety switch may be stuck, intermittent, out of adjustment or disconnected due to running over a tree branch or other debris.

Put your foot on the brake, turn on the ignition and move the shift lever *briskly* from **Park** all the way to **Low** and back to **Park** several times. Leave it in **Park**.

See if it starts.

If it does not, repeat the process but end with the transmission in **Neutral**. See if it starts.

If it does not start, return to **Park**. As HandyHowie suggests, the next step will be to measure voltage at the starter relay while you attempt to start it. This normally takes two people and a voltmeter. The results of that test will determine the next steps in diagnosis.